# Program (c#) Running Elevated, Still Can't Access Some Files

Tags: c#, windows, uac

My code is running elevated but nothing can see/execute c:\windows\system32\rstrui.exe (System Restore Point UI).

I double checked to make sure the code really was running elevated (it is), and I've tested with File.Exist() and Directory.GetFiles() and System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(); file not found is what is returned.

The program is really there, I can really run it, I can copy/paste the path to DOS and list it, execute it (no hidden spaces, etc.).

Any ideas?

THE SOLUTION:

Tim (below) gave me the solution, instead of referencing c:\windows\system32 reference c:\windows\sysnative.  The "sysnative" gets redirected, or, well, doesn't.  I'm still a bit confused about x64 redirection stuff.  The point is, the following works:

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\sysnative"

Thanks Tim!

Comment: Do you have any kind of antivirus or software intercepting the call? That's my initial theory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me guess... you're running as an x86 application on a 64 bit installation of Windows?
I'm not sure of the reason, but [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/050df01f-eb61-49c1-9109-3c1954dcf794) provides some information.
If you compile it for native 64 bit (or Any CPU I suppose) instead of x86, it'll find the file properly.

The reason for this is the System Folder Redirection that's going on in 64bit OS's on applications that are running under WOW64. You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx). One particularly relevant chunk of that post is talking about how to get around it:

> Applications can control the WOW64
>   file system redirector using the
>   [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743%28v=VS.85%29.aspx),
>   [Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365744%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and
>   [Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365745%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
>   functions. Disabling file system
>   redirection affects all file
>   operations performed by the calling
>   thread, so it should be disabled only
>   when necessary for a single CreateFile
>   call and re-enabled again immediately
>   after the function returns. Disabling
>   file system redirection for longer
>   periods can prevent 32-bit
>   applications from loading system DLLs,
>   causing the applications to fail.
>
> 32-bit applications can access the
>   native system directory by
>   substituting %windir%\Sysnative for
>   %windir%\System32. WOW64 recognizes
>   Sysnative as a special alias used to
>   indicate that the file system should
>   not redirect the access. This
>   mechanism is flexible and easy to use,
>   therefore, it is the recommended
>   mechanism to bypass file system
>   redirection. Note that 64-bit
>   applications cannot use the Sysnative
>   alias as it is a virtual directory not
>   a real one.

I was unable to get the `%windir%\Sysnative` idea working, but I'm hopeful that either that works for you or you can implement the enabling/disabling of redirection.

Comment: You just might be a psychic!  I do need this to be a x86 app, and I am on x64.  But, I'm very, very confused.  How could Directories.GetFile() not list a file???  Are you suggesting it only lists x86 apps when running x86? That would seem utterly bizarre.  I must run x86, surely there is a way around this, if this is what's going on.

Comment: You are correct!  I recompiled as x64 and sure enough, the file is found.  But...  I really, really need to call this thing from x86.  Surely there's another way to test the existence of and launch an x64 app from an x86 one.

Comment: I edited my post with more information about why its doing it and a couple options for you to take to get around it.

Comment: Tim, thank you sooo much!  Needless to say it was profoundly confusing and I'd completely forgotten about all the weird x64 redirection stuff which I'll now read up on.  I'll post the solution I find once I get it working.